# Synchronize Styleesheets edited by site moderator

Tags: css, deployment, version-control

I have an asp.net mvc file, but the problem is independent to any technology:

We are planing a new version of our website with an improved design. To improve the site based on seo aspects and conversion rate our site moderators need to do a lot of changes. In our previous version they told me what they want to change and I changed it and deployed it. But this process is too complicated. Therefore I had the idea to add an editor to the backend with some preprocessing like LESS compilation and so on. Works fine, but the question is how to synchronize this files with the current version in the source control system.

I dont need any technical advice, but I would like to hear how you manage your css files and template in your current project.

Answer (score 0):

The main idea is to manage that kind of server-side modification of files in its own branch.

That way you can build an history of css file versions in that dedicated branch, while making changes to those same files *and* many others (for other reasons) on the development machine side, in a separate branch.

You can then reconcile the two histories whenever you want.

Trying to do everything in the same branch is complex, because you would modify many files on the development side (in the course of your daily development activity), while modifying css files on the server.
The risk of overriding one history (css modified on the server) with another (many files modified, but not those css) would be high.

With two separate branches, even if you deploy the wrong version, you can still merge back the css modification done in one branch into the other.